# how to load geometryCollection of geojson file in d3

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js, geojson

I successfully converted a UK map shapefile to geojson using mapshapers. But I am unable to load this geojson in d3.js. Please help. script is as follows.

```
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script>

var canvas = d3.select("body").append("svg")
        .attr("width", 760)
        .attr("height", 700)

        d3.json("Areas_uk_geo.json", function (data) {
            var group = canvas.selectAll("g")
                .data(data.geometries)
                .enter()
                .append("g");

            var projection = d3.geo.mercator();
            var path = d3.geo.path.projection(projection);

            var areas = group.append("path")
                .attr("d", path)
                .attr("class", "area");
        });
</script>
```

The geojson file has a geometryCollection instead of featureCollection.
The geojson file is of the below mentioned format.

```
{
    "type" : "GeometryCollection",
    "geometries" : [{
            "type" : "MultiPolygon",
            "coordinates" : [[[[-2.2241804372470533, 56.88745481725907],
```

.... }, ... and so on.

The error I am getting is "d3.geo.path.projection is not a function"

Comment: I think it should be d3.geo.path().projection(projection);

Answer (score 0):

As mentionned in @vincent-beltman comment, it should be

```
d3.geo.path().projection(projection);
```

You can confirm this with Mike Bostock post ["Let’s Make a Map"](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/map/)