# D3js Map : GeometryCollection Vs FeaturesCollection

Tags: d3.js, geojson

I've been drawing maps for few weeks now but everytime i had that kind of geojson file (Featurecollection). Basicaly multiple arrays of coordinates for different neighborhoods of casablanca (in my example)

> {"type": "FeatureCollection","crs": { "type": "name", "properties": {
>   "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84" }     },  "features": [{
>         "type": "Feature",      "properties": {             "name": "sid elkhader",
>             "arrondissement": "Hay Hassani",            "prefecture": "Hay Hassani",
>             "Population": 18930,            "area": 1616340.045         },      "geometry": {
>             "type": "Polygon",          "coordinates": [
>                 [
>                     [-7.686476562432639, 33.559325447129368],
>                     [-7.690429687499997, 33.557167523684669],
>                     [-7.690712466572602, 33.55630146957499],
>                     [-7.69193172454834, 33.557239049346535],
>                     [-7.6959228515625, 33.56135167528992],
>                     [-7.696309089660644, 33.561208630718284],
>                     [-7.696545124053955, 33.561494719624619],
>                     [-7.697145938873291, 33.561584122213503],
>                     [-7.698111534118651, 33.562549664276048],
>                     [-7.696180343627932, 33.56406947713436],
>                     [-7.698715871374095, 33.566658445267336],
>                     [-7.697645503668443, 33.567405785590324],
>                     [-7.697098054802192, 33.567712878788591],
>                     [-7.696259117371391, 33.568261506969215],
>                     [-7.696011511349325, 33.5683181977139],
>                     [-7.697387200000034, 33.570266599999982],
>                     [-7.696740007740531, 33.570256969950947],
>                     [-7.695561836061942, 33.570528261065235],
>                     [-7.694268410063101, 33.570921223641093],
>                     [-7.693596744041679, 33.571075056616195],
>                     [-7.692447518598163, 33.571143296338079],
>                     [-7.69142000156123, 33.571163408675481],
>                     [-7.690155388704593, 33.57138033300906],
>                     [-7.689247978305328, 33.571612665313971],
>                     [-7.688806874513382, 33.571727285593433],
>                     [-7.688311409275937, 33.571857958148009],
>                     [-7.687409400000027, 33.572054400000049],
>                     [-7.687391678068598, 33.572059961946792],
>                     [-7.684979438782096, 33.568718150423749],
>                     [-7.683219909667969, 33.565678661594823],
>                     [-7.683406457011668, 33.563482296958043],
>                     [-7.683829534164441, 33.562429900601146],
>                     [-7.686476562432639, 33.559325447129368]
>                 ]           ]       }   }, {        "type": "Feature",      "properties": {             "name": "nassim",           "arrondissement": "Hay Hassani",            "prefecture": "Hay
>   Hassani",             "Population": 18898,            "area": 4776317.152         },
>         "geometry": {           "type": "Polygon",          "coordinates": [
>                 [
>                     [-7.665259712372787, 33.530737914470194],
>                     [-7.663579428308825, 33.5378162517151],
>                     [-7.660416146883682, 33.53687582432655],
>                     [-7.653830735645996, 33.533727400613216],
>                     [-7.653876700000025, 33.5326443],
>                     [-7.65348, 33.531745500000149],
>                     [-7.653190299999866, 33.529947799999803],
>                     [-7.652943599999785, 33.528677899999671],
>                     [-7.653615699999913, 33.526604099999851],
>                     [-7.653936200000107, 33.525365200000174],
>                     [-7.654509399999957, 33.5241387],
>                     [-7.655106500000205, 33.522667000000347],
>                     [-7.656280299999967, 33.520306199999879],
>                     [-7.656956199999512, 33.519349099999339],
>                     [-7.658114900000093, 33.517926900000134],
>                     [-7.658983900000114, 33.516343700000149],
>                     [-7.659490200000375, 33.515535600000646],
>                     [-7.6601104, 33.5145457],
>                     [-7.660947299999948, 33.513347099999926],
>                     [-7.662599500000061, 33.511602700000104],
>                     [-7.664262500000047, 33.510654500000086],
>                     [-7.666333199999984, 33.509563099999966],
>                     [-7.668178499999983, 33.50827],
>                     [-7.668900600000119, 33.507543800000242],
>                     [-7.669823299999847, 33.506934599999816],
>                     [-7.670733100000266, 33.507059900000414],
>                     [-7.673713600000018, 33.50863970000001],
>                     [-7.676073900000079, 33.509053],
>                     [-7.68223779133892, 33.508502572767156],
>                     [-7.684989189541704, 33.508844023847608],
>                     [-7.683734893798827, 33.512559745083195],
>                     [-7.675151824951172, 33.519357925734134],
>                     [-7.674551010131836, 33.520717497758142],
>                     [-7.671031951904296, 33.524796085610056],
>                     [-7.668800354003906, 33.526441777122507],
>                     [-7.668285369873048, 33.528516734826688],
>                     [-7.665259712372787, 33.530737914470194]
>                 ]           ]       }   } ....

Now, since i'm exporting geojson files from openstreemap [http://polygons.openstreetmap.fr/index.py](https://github.com/topojson/topojson/issues/37) i'm having that type of geojson (GeometryCollection) for a specific town (no neighborhoods, only the form of a town)

> {"type":"GeometryCollection","geometries":[{"type":"MultiPolygon","coordinates":[[[[-5.9429266,35.745548300000003],[-5.9379208,35.743288800000002],[-5.9327023,35.7417388],[-5.9272307,35.741231999999997],[-5.9202848,35.741909499999998],[-5.9166306,35.746408000000002],[-5.9156028,35.7496942],[-5.9046272,35.760035999999999],[-5.9001726,35.762371000000002],[-5.8900896,35.7656931],[-5.8790518,35.756111199999999],[-5.8770798,35.7525902],[-5.8737711,35.745343900000002],[-5.872858,35.742017500000003],[-5.8727035,35.741004699999998],[-5.8699858,35.732553199999998],[-5.869492,35.731017299999998],[-5.8673423,35.728874099999999],[-5.8638447,35.7260068],[-5.8619479,35.7246934],[-5.8556436,35.720934100000001],[-5.8510603,35.719324399999998],[-5.8464426,35.716996799999997],[-5.8434943,35.714585599999999],[-5.8387091,35.711292700000001]
>   ....

Here are my questions :

1. When i try to draw the map with the Geometrycollection geojson type, i'm having a huge square with a blank point, is it because i'm only having 1 single array of coordinates and not multiple like the 1st example ???
2. How can i structure a new geojson file to use the coordinates of the Geomtrycollection into a FeatureCollection (since it works only with that type) ???

I've been searching a lot [Tip 1](https://github.com/topojson/topojson/issues/37) and here [Tip 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27563382/how-to-load-geometrycollection-of-geojson-file-in-d3) and here [Tip 3](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/165303/geojson-how-to-style-features-of-geometrycollection)
but i couldn't find my answer

Thank y'all for your help

Comment: could you please share the code which actually draws the maps?

Comment: @Elias, here's the Plunker link : http://plnkr.co/edit/MbhmpGmi4nP7o3xR1Cxg?p=info  2 json files (Marrakech with original FeatureCollection  and Test with FeatureCollection that i created based on the GeometryCollection type i had from Openstreetmap. Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't manage to render the `Test.json` file, so I used `mapshaper` in order to transform it to a GeoJSON that we could actually read. Then use the new perks in d3 for geo data `fitSize` is amazing and takes care of all the centering and measuring of your GeoJSON.

```
 #Test.json transformed
 {
     "type":"FeatureCollection",
     "features":[
     {
         "type":"Feature",
         "properties":{

         },
         "geometry":{
             "type":"Polygon",
             "coordinates":[
```

Your logic is fine :) just using the new d3 methods.

```
  d3.json(fichier, function(json) {
    var projection = d3.geoMercator().fitSize([w, h], json);
    var path = d3.geoPath().projection(projection);
    svg.selectAll('path')
      .data(json.features)
      .enter()
      .append('path')
      .attr('d', path)
      .style("fill", "red")
      .style("stroke-width", "1")
      .style("stroke", "black")
      .on("mouseover", function(d) {
        //console.log(d);
      });
  });
```

Here is an updated plnkr http://plnkr.co/edit/MHsC4J2xFC0nrHXSZQGQ?p=preview

Comment: Muchas gracias hermano. Never heard of fitsize before ^^ much appreciated

Comment: No problem, if this solve the issue please mark the answer as useful :) buen dia!